# IPointerClickHandler doesn't work on unity game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have unity 2D project and I wanted to detect left click event on the player game object.

1. I added Physics2DRaycaster to MainCamera *(see the first screen below)*
2. I added two colliders to the game object (the circle collider is for detecting collisions, the box collider is triggered and used for click detection through IPointer) *(see the second screen below)*
3. I implemented the interfaces: IPointerClickHandler,
   IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerDownHandler in the game object script. *(see the code below)*
4. I have EventSystem object in scene *(see the third and fourth screen below)*
5. I checked with a simple project that this combination works

But still in my project any click event isn't detecting at all. I have not idea why. I think the raycast itself doesn't work, because when I look at EventSystem logs in inspector I see that the player object doesn't detected.

**UPDATE: I saw that if I switch off the canvas the IPointer gets work. But canvas elements is placed only around the player gameObject (menu buttton), but the game object isn't hided by the canvas**

**UPDATE 2: Ok, I figured out that even if the canvas panel is transparent it still hides the game objects. So my question is, how can I detect click on game object if the canvas pannel is in front of the game object?**

This is the script of the game object:

```
public class Player : MovingCharacter, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Down");
    }
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked");
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }

    //other code......
}
```

This is the MainCamera:

[image]

This is my Game Object (Player):

[image]

This is the EventSystem:

[image]

And this is the project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)!

If you want to be able to hit the object then put your menu on a special layer like e.g. `UI` and make sure the `PhysicsRaycaster2D` ignores that layer.

UI will be Interactable anyway since the Canvas's own raycaster already takes care of UI elements.

In general I would also make sure to only mark these elements as `Raycast Target` that are actually Interactable (e.g. buttons). This way an invisible background panel wouldn't block the input either.